# Slip boundary conditions for solid-solid interactions?

Tags: solid-state-physics, solid-mechanics

If the no-slip conditions are mostly considered for fluid-solid interactions, so what about solid-solid? Apart from the slip (zero-normal velocity) conditions, are there another consideration that we may have to take into account?

Thanks

Comment: The no-slip conditions are part of fluid dynamics. Solid-solid interactions are not.

Comment: That's I am saying on first place. I just want to figure out what happens when solids are interacting with each other?